# Having problem with dtermining the path over which a line integral is to be evaluated

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Let $C$ be the curve of intersection of $z=xy ; x^2+y^2=1$ traversed once in a direction that appears counterclockwise  when viewed from High above the $xy$-plane ; then how to evaluate $\int_Cydx+zdy+xdz$ ? I have found a parametrization of the curve which is $\Big(\cos t ,\sin t , \dfrac {\sin 2t}2\Big)$ , but I cannot make any whereabout of what does "counterclockwise  when viewed from High above the $xy$-plane "mean . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking down from the $z$ axis the $z$ component of your path looks invisible.  So essentially you just need to confirm that $(\cos(t), \sin(t))$ traverses in the correct direction.  If it does, then you're good.  If not, you'll have to switch all the $t$'s (in all $3$ coordinates) to $-t$'s.

Comment: @Bye_World : I don't get what you mean when you say "looking down from $z$-axis , $z$-component looks invisible". Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Imagine being hundreds of feet in the air looking down on the Great Wall of China.  The wall is very tall but from your position you can only see the tops of the wall (the part parallel to the ground), not the sides (the part of the wall perpendicular to the ground).

Comment: [Here's](https://0bf196087c14ed19d1f11cf1-ambercreativelab.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/animated-headline-effect-preview.gif) an animation which might help.  You can clearly see the plane at every point along its rotation except when it just at the right angle from your position that it disappears.

Comment: where did you get this question from? This is the last question of ma - 105 end semester examination at IITB.

Comment: As far as the answer is concerned, you need to see here that the the curve along the intersection of the two surfaces lies on a cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and therefore you just need to see if the parameterisation of  your curve is such that the projection of the curve on the xy - plane, which is a circle, is traversed in anti clockwise direction or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are right with that parametrization. Here's what this intersection curve looks like when plotted in Mathematica:
[img1 http://puu.sh/lINR8/862057487a.png](http://puu.sh/lINR8/862057487a.png)
What it means to be in the clockwise orientation is that, if you looked at this from above, you would be going around the "circloid" in the counterclockwise direction. See the image below:
[img2 http://puu.sh/lINUY/e76e85992f.png](http://puu.sh/lINUY/e76e85992f.png)
I hope that makes sense. Another way to think about the counterclockwise direction is increasing $\theta$. Think about the unit circle; going counterclockwise yields more positive values of $\theta$. Clockwise gives negative values of $\theta$
In this case, you can imagine $t$ as $\theta$. As $t$ increases, you move counterclockwise on the parametrization.
If you plug $C$ into your line integral, you should be able to calculate it quite easily. I will show the first term, $y\,dx$, and let you go from there.
$y=\sin{t}. \frac{\,dx}{\,dt}=-\sin{t}$, so $dx=-\sin{t}\,dt.$
Therefore, $y\,dx=\sin^2{t}\,dt.$
Do the same for the rest of the terms, factor out the $\,dt$ and integrate.
One final note: this parametrization has $t\in[0, 2\pi]$. That means as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$, the curve is traversed just once. This is generally the case for parametric equations like the one in this example.